# Naming convention for nested block variables (causing variable shadows warnings)

Tags: ios, coding-style, naming-conventions

Just curious, in this example:

```
[array1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   [array2 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      //
   }];
}];
```

Whats the best practice to rename the inner block variables (obj, idx, stop) so that it does not shadow the outer variable? idx2, stop2 seems hacky but sometimes makes the most sense (consider when more than 2 blocks are involved)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can rename them to whatever you like:

```
[array1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj1, NSUInteger idx1, BOOL *stop1) {
   [array2 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj2, NSUInteger idx2, BOOL *stop2) {
       //
   }];
}];
```

Not to say that simply appending a number at the end is the desired solution but just showing that you can name those parameters whatever you like.  You don't have to stick with the example XCode stubs out for you.

Comment: I'm aware that you can - just wanted to see what the community standard is in these situations (if there even is one).

Comment: I would use the same convention or strategy for naming normal method parameters.  Try to make your parameter names descriptive for the next guy.  So maybe 'obj1' is 'userProject' and obj2 is 'projectTask'... the goal IMO is to strive to make the code as readable as possible.  Hope this helps